# Python getter/setter inner function

Tags: python-3.x, methods, closures

I have a class Color that has a method rgb, what I wanted to do was add three inner functions r, g and b that each return the respective values of my rgb property. I just can't seem to access those inner functions from an instantiated object.

The __rgb property is a tuple of three values whose I want to be able to access with Color.rgb.r, Color.rgb.g, Color.rgb.b

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
    @property
    def rgb(self):
        return self.__rgb

        def r(self):
            return self.__rgb[0]
        def g(self):
            return self.__rgb[1]
        def b(self):
            return self.__rgb[2]

    @rgb.setter
    def rgb(self, value):
        self.__rgb = value

        def r(self, value):
            self.__rgb[0] = value
        def g(self, value):
            self.__rgb[1] = value
        def b(self, value):
            self.__rgb[2] = value
```

Getter and setter both throw AttributeError "'list' object has no attribute 'r'".

Is there any way to do this in Python or are inner functions/closures not capable/used of/for that?

Greetings,
Frame

Comment: because I have set more than one method (e.g. luv, lab, etc.). And as you can see luv and lab would both have an 'L' and rgb and lab both have a 'B'. That is why I was trying to solve it by using nested functions

Comment: of course I could name them rgb_r, rgb_g, rgb_b. But I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should switch to using composition of custom classes instead of trying to nest methods. Have a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) (or [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) if you want immutability), have it hold the `r`, `g`, and `b` values, then give it to `Color`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class RGB:
    r: int
    g: int
    b: int

@dataclass
class Color:
    rgb: RGB
    # luv: ?
    # lab: ?

>>> c = Color(RGB(1, 2, 3))
>>> c.rgb.r
1
```

I'm not sure what `luv` and `lab` are, but if they rely on the values given to `rgb`, you could make `rgb` a property, and set them when someone tries to change `rgb`.

This could also be done without `dataclass`es by just using plain classes as before, but unless you really need the control, and *really* want ""private"" attributes, a bare `dataclass` is probably the cleaner option.